# d3 .tsv file does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi i have just started on using d3 as a data visualisation tool and I was following this tutorial: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

However, my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}

</style>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 420,
    barHeight = 20;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width);

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  chart.attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
      .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}

</script>
```

where the tutorial says to use d3.tsv does not work, as compared to a harrd coded html. can anyone shed some light on this? I've placed the `data.tsv` file in the same folder already.

This is my .tsv file:

```
name    value
Locke   4
Reyes   8
Ford    15
Jarrah  16
Shephard    23
Kwon    42
```

Comment: Is your .tsv correct format?

Comment: Hi @Tom ive attached my .tsv file. it is straight off the tutorial..

Comment: do you open that html file in a server?

Comment: I have copied your code. it was not working here too, showing error related to NaN. But just rearranging tsv file.Press tab between name and value values,it works fine>maintain space clearly

Comment: @Tom yes ive used a http server.

Comment: @Roshanjha ive tried tabbing between the numbers and names but it still doesnt work...

Comment: Is there anything in the console window?

Comment: @ChristopherHackett nope. no errors. no nothing. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading the tsv file with chrome from your computer, you need to setup a server on your computer as explained [in the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki#using)

> When developing locally, note that your browser may enforce strict
>   permissions for reading files out of the local file system. If you use
>   d3.xhr locally (including d3.json et al.), you must have a local web
>   server. For example, you can run Python's built-in server:
>
> ```
> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The server part is right. I am running a simple node server my self but ran across a similar issue following along with the vertical bar chart tutorial part 3: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/

So if you are using a server to serve up your data file what ever it may be just make sure to double check the function that coerces a column values to a numbers if you have just copied the code. There is an error in that code for that particular .tsv file.

letter  frequency
A   .08167
B   .01492
C   .02782
D   .04253
E   .12702
F   .02288
G   .02015
H   .06094
I   .06966
J   .00153
K   .00772
L   .04025
M   .02406
N   .06749
O   .07507
P   .01929
Q   .00095
R   .05987
S   .06327
T   .09056
U   .02758
V   .00978
W   .02360
X   .00150
Y   .01974
Z   .00074

Just change this:

```
function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}
```

to this:

```
function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.frequency; // coerce to number
  return d;
}
```

Other wise you will get an error because of this NaN value:

```
 {
   frequency: ".08167"
   letter: "A"
   value: NaN
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was that the editor, Atom in my case, was translating Tab to Spaces.

In Atom go to **Preferences > Tab Type** and set it to **Hard**.