# d3.tsv to load tsv file not working

Tags: d3.js

First, I'm well aware that this question have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132278/d3-tsv-file-does-not-work).

But since the above question is still un-answered, and I cannot find a solution that work for me there, (and I don't have sufficient reputation to post a comment) as a `d3.js` newbie,  I feel the need to bring this to attention.

My code is taken straight from the tutorial [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Barchart II Load Data</title>
  <style>
   .chart rect {
     fill: steelblue;
   }

   .chart text {
     fill: white;
     font: 10px sans-serif;
     text-anchor: end;
   }
   </style>
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <svg class="chart"></svg>
  <script>
    var width = 420, barHeight = 20;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
           .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
           .range([0, width]);

    var chart = d3.select(".chart")
           .attr("width", width)
           .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

    d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {  
      console.log(data);
      x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.value; })]);

      chart.attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

      var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

      bar.append("rect")
              .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
              .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

       bar.append("text")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
              .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
  });

  function type(d) {
      d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
      return d;
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

- I have already installed a local server in my laptop (Wampserver)
- I have put the `data.tsv` in the same folder with the `.html` file
- Run the code from my local Wampserver, it does not work.
- I'm sure the `data.tsv` file have been formatted properly (tab between fields, to create new row, pres Enter)
- Since the above doesn't work, I've tried to put the file online at my site [here](http://pristineparadise.com/practices/d3js/barchartLoadTSV.html), put the "data.tsv" in the same folder, still not working, wether it is offline or online. (the "data.tsv" can be seen [here](http://pristineparadise.com/practices/d3js/data.tsv))
- the `console.log(data)` in Mozilla Firefox on both offline and online displays

  ```
  "ReferenceError: data is not defined"
  ```

  .

Comment: As a test (to check for correct use of tabs in your tsv file), replace it with a shortened csv file (using d3.csv of course) and see if you get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the TSV, but something else: you are using `data` *before* the function `d3.tsv`, in these two variables:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);
```

If you remove them, your code will work, `data.tsv` is correctly loaded. Check the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/dYarVszdkhIBqn4UUly6?p=preview